# In GitLab, do I need to re-merge a branch because I added a new file to my branch?

Tags: merge, gitlab

I'm trying to make sure all of my code is in the right place and it should all be "merged" with an existing project.

I forked their project and merged when I had two source files, and now I've uploaded a third file to mine.

Do I need to remerge my branch with their project for them to see the new file?  If so, how would I do that?  (I get an error about there already being a merge request)

Thank you.

Comment: Why not add the file to the same branch?

Comment: I think I did?  If that's all that's necessary I think I'm all set.  Thank you for the response, by the way.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you did so far. "Uploading" is not a git command

Comment: I used the gitlab interface to get a file on my computer up to the gitlab branch by pressing the "+" button.  I now see the file in my branch.